# Cannot implicitly convert type 'IQueryable' to Generic.IList' Retrieve list of records as List from EF context

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a method:

1.

```
public ActionResult<List<CountryMst>> GetStateById(int countryId)
{
     // return specific column
     var stateList = databaseContext.statemaster
                        .Where(a => a.countryMstId == countryId)
                        .Select(a => new { a.stateId, a.stateName});
     return stateList;
                        
}

public class CountryMst
{
     [Key]
     public int countryId { get; set; }

     public string countryName { get; set; }
}


public class StateMst
{
     [Key]
     public int stateId { get; set; }

     public string stateName { get; set; }

     public CountryMst countryMst { get; set; }

     public int countryMstId { get; set; }

}
```

and error in selected place :
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int stateId, string stateName>>' to
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult
<System.Collections.Generic.List<AngularWebApi.Entity.Entities.CountryMst>>'

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: i used ToList() at the end but didn't work

Comment: From the error message, you are returning an anonymous type within your `Select` but the method should be returning type of `CountryMst` - have you looked into that?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explaining the problem pretty well here:

```
.Select(a => new { a.stateId, a.stateName})
```

returns a `System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int stateId, string stateName>>` which is something you can not cast to `List<AngularWebApi.Entity.Entities.CountryMst>` (without explicitly explaining how).
Meaning, you need to use your class in the select:

```
.Select(a => new CountryMst
   { 
      countryId = a.stateId, 
      countryName = a.stateName,
   }) 
.ToList()
```